# Office Web Apps doesn't open documents in Project Server 2013 sites

Tags: office-web-apps, project-server

**Hello everyone.** 
After "March 14, 2017, cumulative update for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB3172497)" I have a problem with opening docs in browser, not on whole farm! Only site collection of project server. I reinstalled office web apps, rebuild bindings... and no result. Please, help.

Error in uls **wac-server**:
*WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [exception:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.FileUnknownException: WOPI 400. Wopi,CheckFile,WACSERVER ---> System.Web.HttpException: BadRequest     --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---     в Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)     в Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End()     в Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()]*

Error in uls **wfe-server**:
*System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client. In System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig () in System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper (HttpContext context)*

Comment: Are you have patched PS 2013 too?!!!

Comment: OMG! 0_0 no, try to install this night =)

Comment: Please Feedback us!

Comment: Unfortunately no result after install march 14 CU for Project Server 2013

Comment: Problem on WHOLE FARM!

Answer (score 0):

Found some bug.

Problem solved if I change site URL (project site url) with only english symbols and without spaces. The problem occurs on project sites which url address contains russian symbols and spaces. And sometimes I see an error if I change url adress and use russian symbols and spaces.

Error text in window of web page:
*A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)*

Screenshot of error:
[image]

Comment: This problem occurs on WHOLE FARM! Not only project sites!

Comment: Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this has been addressed in the April 2017 CU:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3178732/april-11-2017-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb3178732

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2da3d100-c3ce-4654-814c-e42f225754cd/error-opening-some-documents-with-office-web-app-server-after-march-2017-cu-installation?forum=sharepointadmin

(I have this happening on my dev farm and am starting to update to the April 2017 CU)